# Running a jquery plugin within a Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to dynamically set the elementID for a element within a directive and  initiate a jquery plugin "charCount".

http://plnkr.co/edit/XkUCJvhM9Fh2JIz7vwc1?p=preview

I can't find the element within the directive.

Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mainly a timing issue. By injecting $timeout, it gives directive enough time to render its template in the dom. Here's the updated plunker.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QtJF529cn76BmNQViSn4?p=preview)